# Coroutine error at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I have a retrofit request:

```
try {
    val response = service.getItems()
    when {
        response.isSuccessful -> handleResponse()
        else -> handleError(Throwable(
        response.errorBody()?.charStream()?.readText()
    ))
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    handleError(e)
}
```

and sometimes I get this exception:

```
  ItemsViewModel$fetchImages$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:100)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(Unknown Source:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Unknown Source:129)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(Unknown Source:2)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(Unknown Source:2)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(Unknown Source:34)
```

It's not consistent and I don't have steps to reproduce. What can be the reason?

Comment: Could you please provide code for `ItemsViewModel$fetchImages` method. There error is there I guess.

Comment: the body of that method is in description. and method "handleResponse" is basically sets the value to livedata